# ffmpeg watermark overlay turns portrait to landscape

Tags: ffmpeg, watermark, portrait

I have an issue with portrait videos : when I add a watermark on it like this

```
ffmpeg -i bb.mov -i watermark.png -filter_complex overlay aa.mp4
```

the aa.mp4 result video is in landscape mode ...

Is there any solution to watermark my portrait video input to get a portrait video output ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally, this works :

```
ffmpeg -i bb.mov -i watermark.png -filter_complex "transpose=1, overlay"  aa.mp4
```